# Firefox "connection was reset" when accessing localhost, but [::1] works

Tags: networking, firefox, localhost

I'm on Windows 10. I'm running a local web server that's listening on `[::1]:5173`. When attempting to connect using Firefox to `http://localhost:5173`, I get a connection reset error. Connecting to `[::1]:5173` works however. Using the Firefox `about:networking` DNS lookup tool, `localhost` resolves to both `127.0.0.1` and `[::1]` Chrome connects to the localhost URL just fine.

Why isn't my `localhost` URL working correctly on Firefox?

Comment: When you say it's listening on [::1]:5173, are you implying that it is NOT also listening on IPv4? If so, your results make it sound like Firefox's Happy Eyeballs support is broken, at least for localhost.

Comment: Correct, it's not listening on 127.0.0.1. If I make the server listen on that address Firefox can use localhost just fine.

Comment: What happens if you leave it listening on IPv6 but not IPv4, but make it so "localhost" only resolves to IPv6? That will help you tell whether Firefox's localhost IPv6 support is completely broken, or if it's just not doing Happy Eyeballs.

Comment: IPv6 addresses need to be enclosed in brackets. Try `http://[::1]` and `http://[localhost]`. (Not sure that the second one can work.)